# PHP strtolower with specical char (like: äüö)

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have problem in PHP converting a string to lowercase when it contains a special char, in this case especially umlauts as i'm dealing with names. The use case here is i'm searching for the name in an array in which the names allready existant in the database are put in lowercase (actually done by `strtolower` which works fine).

The Problem is, that converting to lower case fails for special characters, which is very strange as it works with the names from the database and in both cases the input is utf8. I even checked the encoding with `mb_detect_encoding($name)` first which returns `UTF-8`.

```
    // All names from the database are read into an array, mysql charset is utf8
    foreach($db_names as $namerow) {
        $name   = $namerow['lastname'] .' '. $namerow['firstname'];
        $allnames[strtolower($name)] = $namerow['id']; // works 
    }

    // Get data from a webservice which return utf-8 encoded data (i checked that)
    $data = ...;

    // Test the utf-8
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    print_r($allnames); // everything is correct here
    var_dump(strtolower($data['name'])); // Output i.e. rÖmer - notice still uppercase char
    var_dump(mb_strtolower($data['name'])); // Output with strange ? character - r?mer
    var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($data['name'])); // Output: UTF-8
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call [`mb_internal_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php) first to tell the multibyte functions what encoding you want them to operate on:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
var_dump(mb_strtolower($data['name']));
```

Or pass the encoding argument directly to `mb_strtolower`:

```
var_dump(mb_strtolower($data['name'], 'UTF-8'));
```

Comment: took a while to find time to try, but your answer is perfect. Does it use the iconv.internal_encoding setting of php? Also very strange is that strtolower can work with utf8 from database but not from the external api...

Comment: It uses the `mbstring.internal_encoding` ini setting.